# ASP.NET MVC: file response streaming?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, streaming

When I return a FilePathResult from an MVC action method, which of the following happens (assuming, if it matters, that the file to which the result points is very large):

1. The file gets loaded in its entirety into the server's memory, and then sent to the client.
2. The file is somehow streamed to the client, in such a way that it is not at any point fully loaded into the server's memory.
3. Something else.

If the answer is 1, is it possible to have the file sent as in 2 instead by returning a different type of result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE: `FilePathResult` uses [response.TransmitFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12s31dhy.aspx) which "Writes the specified file directly to an HTTP response output stream, without buffering it in memory.". [Here's the source code for MVC](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases).

You can stream data back using the `FileStreamResult` class:

```
 return new FileStreamResult(stream, "application/pdf")
 {
     result.FileDownloadName = "somefile.pdf";
 };
```

Or you could redirect to the file like this:

```
 return Redirect("somefile.pdf");
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure FilePathResult doesn't do a redirect - as the msdn document says, it "sends the contents of a file to the response".

Comment: Actually, `FileStreamResult` doesn't seem to stream directly. It still copies the whole file into memory.

Comment: Using `Response.BufferOutput = false;` helps in this case, though.

Comment: And also note that setting `Response.BufferOutput = false;`, when obtaining the file stream through some async method from within the controller method, will deadlock.