# securely show images on website

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, image

I currently store a number of document preview images (jpg/tif) outside of my web root. There are 100s of them, so having this work efficiently is important.
The reason they are stored outside of the web root is that they contain data the only specific users/user groups may view (but each user can have 100s of documents they can view).

My current implementation is, when the user selects ‘view image’ an ajax call is triggered and this moves the image in question to a specific folder within the web root. The location is passed back and used to display the image to the user.
When the next image is clicked, the call deletes any existing images and copies over the requested image.  At session logout / timeout the users image folder is emptied.
This has a few problems, but mainly:

1. Files are constantly being copied and deleted
2. There is the risk of images being left in the folder (issues with log off scripts)
3. The whole time an images is in the folder it could be viewed by another users (unlikely but possible)

Is there a better way of doing this? I looked at trying to combine the BinaryReader with the ajax call (as I hoped this would cut out the need to copy the files), but can’t see how to get the data back to be used by the JS in the calling page.

Alternatively is there a way of making selected Folders only accessible to given users based on some session criteria? (I can’t imagine there is but I thought it’s worth asking.)

So if anyone has any ideas on how this can be improved that would be great.
This is a c# ASP.NET app using Jquery.

Edit:
The image is displayed using ajax, this allows for preloading and also means the rest of the page does not need to be reloaded when they select the next/previous image.
It can almost be thought of as a javascript image swapper type situation, where the images are stored outside of the web root.

Thanks.

Comment: Save the images with a random name (e.g. Guid) and store a reference (user <-> image) in the database.

Comment: Hi Andreas, that is basically what I am currently doing. I'm looking for a way to avoid copying/renaming the files.

Comment: Then why the copying/renaming when nobody knows the image names? Just forbid the direct access to the image folder and only serve the images via a script that checks the permissions of the user

Comment: The copying and renaming is because I have little faith in security through obscurity. The image folder is currently outside of the web root, so no one can access it. And the images are currently only served via a script that does check the permissions. But as Steve rightly points out (and the reason for my original post) is that is is a 'horrible idea' and I'm trying to find a better one. With the same functionality.

Comment: I think for your requirement you should use database for saving file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was how to get an image to show via javascript that is not in the web root.

I created a generic handler (ashx file) that based on the session values (authentication) and submitted parameters would return an image.

That in turn is being called via AJAX.

Answer (score 1):

> My current implementation is, when the user selects ‘view image’ an ajax call is triggered and this moves the image in question to a specific folder within the web root.

This is horrible idea. You realize you can just access the image data and pass it to web as stream with specific mime type, right?

Comment: Hi Steve, are you referring to using BinaryReader and then passing those bytes back with the appropriate mime type?

Comment: @jimmy Yes, serve file directly from where it is. Just remember to check permissions first to know if the one who's requesting it actually can view it.

Comment: the permissions part is sorted. I just cant find a way to pass back the BinaryReader results via Jquery/ajax.

Comment: @jimmy It's fairly simple. It also has nothing to do with jQuery. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16845681/asp-net-mvc-file-response-streaming

Comment: I've added some more info to explain why I'm using ajax.

Comment: @jimmy Javascript or no javascript content is loaded the same way. Just because you use AJAX does not mean that you need to serve the content somehow differently.

Comment: This gives me some hope, I know how to serve files using BinaryReader, but I don't know how to use that in an ajax call. Could you point me in the right direction? Basically the first click shows them the first image and then there are next/prev options that should then load the appropriate images. I need to use ajax to avoid reloading the page due to everything else on it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to write a method that will check user credentials by cookies, if it is not OK then load and send back some standard image that will say that user must log in to view file, if it is ok then load and show proper file from a path outside of root based on url parameter (with proper headers like [content-type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.contenttype.aspx) also often referred as [mime-type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775147.aspx) ofc). Then link urls to that method with proper parameter(s).

You can easily find examples of code (like [here](http://aspalliance.com/1322_Displaying_Images_in_ASPNET_Using_HttpHandlers.5)) to display image in binary form from DB. You would need just to load them from some path outside of root, not DB.

Also you don't need to load it by AJAX - just add IMG with SRC pointing to URL of handler. Or redirect / open window if it needs to be downloaded not shown.

Comment: I've added some more info to the original post explaining why I'm using (and want to continue using) ajax

Comment: Using img element created dynamically by JS is also asynchronous and works without page reload. It has nearly all properties that ajax has. It's just not AJAX in strict way.

Comment: When I mean adding IMG dynamically I mean something like that (simplistic code just to show idea): http://jsfiddle.net/kVZ5G/